# JWPlayer inside a Bootstrap4 modal lose focus

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, focus, jwplayer

I load a jwplayer inside a Bootstrap4 modal the simple way.

```
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("video_container");
playerInstance.setup({
file: mediaUrl;
autostart: true;
});
</script>
```

But the player lose his focus and I can't control it with the spacebar.

I try a lot of

```
$('#video_container .jw-icon-playback').focus();
```

on each element of the player but it seems it doesn't work (or maybe I miss the only one who works...).

Does anyone encountered this case?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can  set a function

`$( ".modal" ).on('shown', function(){ //PUT  YOUR CODE HERE });`